# MySQL: Check if a value already exists before trying to update a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to perform a check if the value that I want to update already exists in a table before updating a column.

For example: if I have table called **Tokens**,  with column called **refresh_token**, and **token**. I only want to update a blank refresh_token only if their exists no other refresh_token with the same value.

I have this:

```
IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Tokens WHERE refresh_token = 'C08Rbs'))
          BEGIN
            UPDATE Tokens SET refresh_token='C08Rbs' WHERE id='2'
          END
        END;
```

but it is returning an error:

`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Tokens WHERE refresh_token = 'C08Rbs' at line` 1

How should I do this?

NOTE: I am not using a stored procedure. I want to do this using one query.

And is there a way I can do it using an if-else statement??. Because if to execute a statement if the value exists

Comment: Add a unique constraint to the column refresh_token!

Comment: You may want to consider adding the  `UNIQUE KEY` attribute to the `refresh_token` column. Then, by virtue of existing, no other record would have the same `refresh_token`. Thus, a necessary query simply answers the question, "**does a record exist?**" Of course, this would depend on how the refresh tokens are being generated, what constitutes a primary or composite key in the `Token` table, and the feasibility of such a setup given the `Token` table's use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one statement:

```
UPDATE Tokens
    SET refresh_token = 'C08Rbs'
    WHERE id = '2' AND
          NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Tokens WHERE refresh_token = 'C08Rbs');
```

EDIT:

Ooops.  In MySQL, you need to do this with a `join`:

```
UPDATE Tokens t CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt
        FROM Tokens
        WHERE refresh_token = 'C08Rbs'
       ) tc
    SET refresh_token = 'C08Rbs'
    WHERE id = '2' AND tc.cnt = 0;
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'Tokens' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
IF (SELECT tocken_id FROM Tokens WHERE refresh_token = 'C08Rbs') IS NOT NULL THEN
          BEGIN
            UPDATE Tokens SET refresh_token='C08Rbs' WHERE id='2'
          END
END IF;
```

Where `tocken_id` is unique field or any field in `Tockens` table.